# Does UIDynamicBehavior only move entire views, or can it affect contentOffset instead?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uidynamicbehavior, uisnapbehavior

I'm having a difficult time understanding `UIDynamicBehaviors`.

I'm trying to add a `UISnapBehavior` to a `UIScrollView`, and as you all know the way `UIScrollViews` behave is by changing its `contentOffset` when the user interacts with it, 
but when I add the `UISnapBehavior`, the entire `UIScrollView` flies off screen.

I won't paste any code because I hope I've misunderstood something basic about this, so:

How can I get a `UIDynamicBehavior/UISnapBehavior` to only affect the `contentOffset` of a `UIScrollView`?